# Base64 encode very large files in objective C to upload file in sharepoint

Tags: objective-c, sharepoint, file-upload, base64, large-files

I have a requirement where user can upload files present in app to SharePoint via same app.

I tried using http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/CopyIntoItems method of sharepoint. But it needs file in base64 encoded format to be embedded into body of SOAP request . My code crashed on device when I tried to convert even a 30 MB file in base64 encoded string? Same code executed just fine on simulator

Is there any other alternative to upload files (like file streaming etc) onto sharepoint?? I may have to upload files upto 500 MB? Is there more efficient library to convert NSData into base64 encoded string for large file???

Should I read file in chunks and then convert that into base64 encoded string and upload file once complete file is converted? Any other appraoches???

Answer (score 1):

First off, your code probably crashed because it ran out of memory. I would do a loop where I read chunks that I converted and then pushed to a open socket. This probably means that you need to go to a lower level than NSURLConnection, I have tried to search for NSURLConnection and chunked upload without much success.

Some seem to suggest using [ASIHttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), but looking at the homepage it seems abandoned by the developer, so I can't recommend that.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) looks really good, it has blocks support and I can see in the example on the first page how it could be used for you. Look at the streaming request example. Basically create a NSInputStream that you push chunked data to and use it in a AFHTTPURLConnectionOperation.